Exporting a table with long raw , but the data in long raw is not moving
I am trying to export a table with long raw. The table size is 800GB. The datapump is not exporting the long raw. I did some research, and it seems the only way is to transfer them to LOB then export/import. Then I have to transfer them again to long raw in another database. Is there another simple way?
I did the below. Notice the size is small. Doing a sum of the table in dba_table is giving around 800GB. I know this datatype is deprecated but I cannot change that for now.
Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 17 23:53:38 2024
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "db1"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  db1/********@sv1 directory=backup dumpfile=tablle1_d.dmp LOGFILE=log_tablle1_d.log TABLES=tablle1
 EXCLUDE=STATISTICS,INDEX parallel=10
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
. . exported "db1"."tablle1"              12.54 MB      77 rows
Master table "db1"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for db1.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  /backup/tablle1_d.dmp
Job "db1"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Tue Dec 17 23:55:21 2024 elapsed 0 00:01:26


The output of the export shows 77 rows and a size of 12.54 MB. A LONG or LONG RAW column cannot be more than 2G, so 77 rows cannot contain more than 154 LONG RAW data. The table contains only one LONG RAW column. So, it is not possible that your table data is 800G. I think that your table contained a lot of rows that you deleted and most of the 800G is space that now is unused.
Export the table, truncate the table, and import the data again. This the usual way to reorganize a table that contains a LONG or LONG RAW column. You can export the table and import it with a different name or in a different schema and check its content, before you do the actual reorganisation.
